# mark all check boxes in internet explorer using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create excel macro which will mark 75 check boxes in a certain table on internet explorer page

the code of that table is :

```
    <TABLE id=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes border=0><TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_0 type=checkbox name=ctl00$MasterMain$ucGenConfig$ucConfigContainer$ucConfigPopup$cblSchemes$0><LABEL for=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_0>Start</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_1 type=checkbox name=ctl00$MasterMain$ucGenConfig$ucConfigContainer$ucConfigPopup$cblSchemes$1><LABEL for=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_1>Start2</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_2 type=checkbox name=ctl00$MasterMain$ucGenConfig$ucConfigContainer$ucConfigPopup$cblSchemes$2><LABEL for=ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_2>Default</LABEL></TD></TR>
    <TR>
```

and so on 
I have tried various ways but it doesn't want to play

```
With IE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes")
    .Item.Click
end with
```

and

```
With IE.document.getElementsByName("checkBoxlist(ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes)")
.Item(0).Checked = True 'Entered
End With
```

and

```
For Each htmlelement In IE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes")
htmlelement.Item(0).Click
Next htmlelement
```

Thanks in advance for any help or leads :)

Comment: why not? what errors/problems do you have?

Comment: I suspect the reason is because none of the checkboxes are named what you are passing in to the `getElementsByName` method, therefore nothing is returned.  It seems like you would need to have a variable, say i, and increment it 1, grab the element, click it, and continue.  Without access to the website I can't test but I can attempt to write some code that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an assumption here that the checkboxes that have an id like this:

```
ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_0
```

Have an identifier that begins at 0, as above, and increments by 1 to 74 (corresponding to your request for 75 checkboxes).

If that is the case, something like this may work:

```
    Dim sBaseName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'The base id of the checkboxes
    sBaseName = "ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_"

    For i = 0 To 74 '75 checkboxes
            ie.Document.getElementByID(sBaseName + CStr(i)).Click
    Next i
```

Of course you must be sure you have set `ie` appropriately, navigated to the page, etc.

This code will first grab and click

```
ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_0
```

Then i increments by 1, so it will grab and click

```
ctl00_MasterMain_ucGenConfig_ucConfigContainer_ucConfigPopup_cblSchemes_1
```

And so on, to 74.